# Change the process scheduling algorithm

Tags: linux, scheduling

I'm running on Linux (Ubuntu), and I want to change the process scheduling algorithm using **chrt** command.

What is the full command to execute ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: It looks like you have to make some effort to avoid an answer when searching. In the meantime, maybe try [`man chrt(1)`](https://www.google.com/search?q=man+chrt).

Comment: @jww I think you got wrong idea about Stack Overflow, just type in Scheduling policies in Linux in search bar and you will see if really your comment is right.

Answer (score 0):

To set scheduling algorithm of process to one of these types:

**SCHED_BATCH (-b or --batch)** or **SCHED_FIFO (-f or --fifo)** or **SCHED_OTHER (-o or --other)** or **SCHED_RR (-r or --rr)** we type:

**sudo chrt -Type -p Priority PID**

Type can take one the of the types above

Priority value depends on scheduling used, you can use **chrt -m** to find min/max value allowed.

PID is the process id

example: **sudo chrt -r -p 50 17588**